# Python Hotmail login

Tags: python

I need a python script that prompts for a username and password and tries to login to Hotmail using those credentials, outputting whether they are valid or not.

Comment: could you try to rephrase this with pseudocode? it's unclear what you're trying to do here. are you writing a web client that logs on to hotmail?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hotmail login!

```
import poplib

M = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop3.live.com', 995) #Connect to hotmail pop3 server
try:
    M.user(raw_input("username: ")) #Get the username from the standar input
    M.pass_(raw_input("password: ")) #Get the password from the standar input
except:
    print "username or password incorrect"
else:
    print "Successful login"
```

**Edit:** since you only need to know if you can do a login, I rewrite the code

If you lose connection during the typing the username or password, I don't know what will happend.

Comment: sir but if password wrong it's show error massage  [[[[        
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hamoud\Desktop\xp.py", line 5, in <module>
    M.pass_(getpass.getpass("password: "))
  File "C:\Python26\lib\poplib.py", line 189, in pass_
    return self._shortcmd('PASS %s' % pswd)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\poplib.py", line 152, in _shortcmd
    return self._getresp()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\poplib.py", line 128, in _getresp
    raise error_proto(resp)
poplib.error_proto: -ERR authentication failed
 ]]]]
so i don't want show error if password wrong !

Comment: Delivered ;D

The netx time try to explain better the problem and also add some code.

Comment: thanks razpeitia
but can you leave your email i wana contact with you

Comment: Sure, it's razpeitia_r1 at hotmail dot com

Answer (score 2):

This is alternative if pop3 failed. just check login using IMAP for hotmail,live or now only outlook.com by using python outlook library you can download here :
https://github.com/awangga/outlook

```
import outlook
mail = outlook.Outlook()
mail.checkLogin()
```

it will attemp username and password for authentication validation.