# python read last line !

Tags: python

My problem is in this code:

```
try:
    PassL = open(sys.argv[3], "r").readlines()
    print "[+] Passwords:",len(PassL),"\n"
except(IOError): 
    print "[-] Error: Check your wordlist path\n"
    sys.exit(1)
    for word in PassL:
        word = word.replace("\r","").replace("\n","")
    login_form_seq = [
    ('log', sys.argv[2]),
    ('pwd', word),
    ('rememberme', 'forever'),
    ('wp-submit', 'Login >>'),
    ('redirect_to', 'wp-admin/')]
    try:
         login_form_data = urllib.urlencode(login_form_seq)
         opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    except:
         print'Unknown ERROR'
    try:
             OP = opener.open(host, login_form_data).read()
    except(urllib2.URLError), msg:
         print msg
         OP = ""
    else:
         'wrong?'
    if re.search("WordPress requires Cookies",OP):
            print "[-] Failed: WordPress has cookies enabled\n"
            sys.exit(1)
        #Change this response if different. (language)
    if re.search("<strong>ERROR</strong>",OP):
         print "[-] Login Failed :",word
    else:
             print "\n[!] Login Successfull:",'[#]The Information:',sys.argv[2],':',word
```

So the problem is, I provide `sys.argv[2]` and that gets the `txt` file. For example:

```
www.py wow.txt
```

Then in my python script I try to login to a web site with the password in wow.txt. The problem is, I put 15 passwords in `wow.txt` and my `www.py` script reads the last line!

The purpose of the script is because I forget a lot of my Wordpress accounts (around six accounts), and actually am thinking of trying 25 passwords for each. So make it easy for me -- don't say "go and try it manually", just give me the code or the right way.

Comment: I urge you to work on your language. Think your question through, read the question out loud before you post it publicly in front of hundreds of thousands of developers. Writing your question properly does make a difference. You do want to be taken seriously, don't you?

Comment: most of your code will only run if attempting to open `sys.argv[3]` raises an `IOError`.

Comment: I would also advise you to make it less obvious that you are a script kiddie:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251237/python-hotmail-login
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246677/python-and-web-field-closed
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436251/login-to-joomla-via-python-and-print-the-login-time

Comment: I'd suggest using your browser's password saving function or having your passwords written down somewhere if you have trouble remembering.

Comment: @bowenl2 I would advise you to concentrate on this question instead of ridiculing OP.

Answer (score 3):

Most of your code never runs at all, because it's in an `except` block **and** unconditionally follows a `sys.exit` -- so execution will never get there, even if the exception does occur to trigger the except (if it doesn't occur of course the whole `except` is never entered).  Look again at the code you posted...:

```
except(IOError): 
    print "[-] Error: Check your wordlist path\n"
    sys.exit(1)
    for word in PassL:
        word = word.replace("\r","").replace("\n","")
    login_form_seq = [  (etc etc)
```

Clearly your indentation is all wrong.  I suspect what you want is:

```
except(IOError): 
    print "[-] Error: Check your wordlist path\n"
    sys.exit(1)
for word in PassL:
    word = word.replace("\r","").replace("\n","")
    login_form_seq = [  (etc etc)
```

that is, deintenting only two lines (so the rest remain part of the loop).

How you could perpetrate such atrocious indentation in your code, I don't know.  Maybe you're using tabs (instead of using 4 spaces, exclusively, for every indent) and your editor or IDE is set in some way that's misleading you about what the indents actually are.

Comment: Alex Martelli .. it's would be better if you leave your email 
i want contact with you

Comment: Hah, I didn't even notice it was all in an except block. You are right though, it looks like those two lines are the ones that need to be fixed. +1

Comment: @str1k3r I don't think anyone will do that. If you have followup questions, post them here again, seek for help in IRC channels or forums.

Answer (score 2):

Your `for word in PassL` loop is only one line long, but it looks as if you probably want the rest of the script to be indented to also be part of that loop.

At the moment, the loop iterates through the list, replacing the variable `word` with a new value (as per the replace commands). When the loop ends, the last value in `word` is the last value in the list (without a line ending).

Increasing the indent on the rest of the script will run all of that code for each line in the file.

Comment: Zooba i don't understand can you explain again ^^"